# If $T^3=T$ show that $V=V_0\oplus V_1\oplus V_2$ , where the $V_i$ are subspaces of $V$ with some special properties.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

The following exercise is from Brown's book, *A Second Course in Linear Algebra*:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and $T\in\mathscr E(V)$ such that $T^3=T$. Show that $V=V_0 \oplus V_1\oplus V_2$ , where the $V_i$ are subspaces of $V$ with the following properties:
> $(a)\ \alpha\in V_0\implies T(\alpha)=0$,
> $(b)\ \alpha\in V_1\implies T(\alpha)=\alpha$,
> $(c)\ \alpha\in V_2\implies T(\alpha)=-\alpha$.
> Assume $2\ne0$ in $F$.

**My Attempt:**
I first showed $V_0 \cap V_1\cap V_2 =\varnothing$. Let $\alpha\in V_0 \cap V_1\cap V_2$. Then $\alpha\in V_0 \implies T(\alpha)=0$. Again, $\alpha\in V_1\implies T(\alpha)=\alpha$. Since $T$ is a linear transformation, this gives us $\alpha=0$.

Next, we need to show $V=V_0+V_1+V_2$ but I have no clue as to how! I've tried the following:
For $v\in V$, we have
\begin{align}
T^3(v)&=T(v)\\
\implies T(T^2(v)-v)&=0
\end{align}
But I don't see how this can be written as three summands to show that $V\subseteq V_0+V_1+V_2$.
Any hints/alternate approaches would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Hint: $T(T-I)(T+I)=0.$

Comment: $x,x-1,x+1$ are coprime polynomials. Write $1$ as a combination of them using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @lhf : All of your terminologies are unknown to me.

Comment: @Fred : Unfortunately, I still do not see how to show $V\subseteq V_0+V_1+V_2$ from your hint. How do I use the fact you mentioned?

Comment: $x(x-1)+x(x+1)-2(x-1)(x+1)=2 \implies T(T-I)+T(T+I)-2(T-I)(T+I)=2I$

Comment: You mustn't write $\emptyset$ for the subspace $\{0\}$.

Comment: You seem to think that the conditions for $V=X\oplus Y\oplus Z$ are $V=X+Y+Z$, $X\cap Y\cap Z=\{0\}$. That's not sufficient, you also need $X\cap (Y+Z)=\{0\}$ etc.

Comment: For any $v:$ $$v=\left(v-T^2v\right)+\Bigg(\frac{T^2v+Tv}{2}\Bigg)+\Bigg(\frac{T^2v-Tv}{2}\Bigg)$$ Moreover, $$v-T^2v\in V_0,\\ \frac{T^2v+Tv}{2}\in V_1,\\ \frac{T^2v-Tv}{2}\in V_2$$ This shows $V=V_0+V_1+V_2$.

Comment: @MatthewH.: I do not see why $v-T^2v\in V_0$ ? We have $$ T(T^2(v)-v)=0 .$$ But that does not imply $v-T^2v\in V_0$ (right?).